# List all files in a directory except for an extension

Tags: batch-file

I wonder how do I show all files in a directory with the exception of an extension.

**Example:** .bat

---

**My code:**

```
Dir /ah-d /b /s "%temp%" >>"Temp.TxT"
```

**Result:**

```
Folder123
image.jpg
TESTE.bat
abc.TMP
```

**Result I want:**

```
Folder123
image.jpg
abc.TMP
```

**Note:** The other files may vary extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the output by piping to FINDSTR, rejecting lines that end with your extension.

The `/L` option treats the search as a literal search (as opposed to a regular expression). The `/E` option only matches if at end of line. The `/I` option makes it case insensitive. The `/V` option inverts the search, keeping lines that don't match, filtering out the lines that do match

```
dir /ah-d /b /s "%temp%" | findstr /live .bat >>"temp.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

This picks up specific extensions - none, jp(eg|g), and tmp.

```
dir /ah-d /b /s "%temp%\*." "%temp%\*.jp*" "%temp%\*.tmp"
```

To exclude pipe the output

```
dir /ah-d /b /s "%temp%\*.*" | Findstr /i /v /c:".bat" >outputfile
```

Comment: This isn't completely reliable - it would exclude anything with `.bat` in it, for example: `this.bat.txt`, `myfile.bat1`

Comment: So what, how likely is it.

Comment: You should never make assumptions about your data.

Comment: Not to mention whateverfile.bat.bak (even if you would probably want to exclude that, too)

Comment: Why would it be in Temp? You people misunderstand system administration versus commercial apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the command line (no batch file needed):

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %A IN (`DIR /B /S "%temp%"`) DO (IF /I NOT "%~xA"==".bat" ECHO %A>>Out.txt)
```

The key piece of this is the `%~xA` part which will return the file extension of the file being processed. This is then compared to the extension you want to exclude (in this case `.bat`) and if it does not match, then the filename is written to the output.

Note that in your example, you are showing directories being returned so my `DIR` command does not exclude them. Additionally, since you are using the `/S` switch, then the full path will be returned. If you only want to get the file name part, just replace:

```
ECHO %A
```

With:

```
ECHO %~nxA
```